# audio not playing in live server codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

below code display the audio, audio tag works perfectly, it play the music in local server, but on live server audio not working, its not playing the music. it is appearing like disabled things in chrome and in mozilla it is not even showing the play button. i think problem is with source url.

```
<audio controls id = "myaudio">
   <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>worship/assets/<?php echo $row->language_folder; ?>/<?php echo $row->album_folder; ?>/<?php echo $row->song_name; ?>" type="audio/mp3"> 
</audio>
```

Please advise me.

Comment: A) Please fix the formatting (4 spaces at the start of each line of code). B) What is the error? There is little to go on here

Comment: you still didn't say what the error is. Have you checked your console for errors? Most likely either the file is not in a format compatible with the browser you're testing with, or the URL is incorrect. We can't really help you with the URL much since we don't know the structure of your application, or whether those folders or files actually exist, and whether they have the correct permissions granted. You can check all of that easily, though. For file format compatibility, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: @ADyson its a mp3 format. there is no error just showing disabled audio button and that is not playing music.

Comment: Not even a 404 or something in the Network tools when it tries to load the file? If you copy the rendered link from the "src" of your control (as seen in your page source) and try to go to it in the browser directly, does it fetch the file? Also as per that link I gave you, the "type" for an MP3 is supposed to be "audio/mpeg". It's there in the documentation if you read it, have you tried setting that to the recommended value?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you :

Just change the `Media Type` OR `MIME-type` from `audio/mp3` to `audio/mpeg`

```
 <source type="audio/mpeg" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>worship/assets/<?php echo $row->language_folder; ?>/<?php echo $row->album_folder; ?>/<?php echo $row->song_name; ?>" >
```

and use `base_url` like  this (just suggestion) ;

```
<source type="audio/mpeg" src="<?php echo base_url('worship/assets/'.$row->language_folder.'/'.$row->album_folder.'/'.$row->song_name); ?>" >
```

For more :
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp

Comment: Thank you for your help @pradeep i got it as u said. MIME was not corrent folders were not in correct order. thank you.